# Failed to load resource (Javascript image.src)

Tags: javascript, loadimage

I want to ask you what's wrong with my code below :

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

var image = new Image();
image.onload = onLoad;
image.src = './PS_Countdown.jpeg';
ctx.drawImage(image, 25, 25);

function onLoad() {
    console.log('Image loaded');
}
```

Comment: Is the image located in that folder?

Comment: according to your error, it can't find that file. Is the location correct? it's `.jpeg`? and the `./` is correct? Also, you may want to move the `drawImage` line into the `onLoad` function so that you HAVE the image before you try to use it

Comment: I changed the extension from .jpeg to .jpg, but id doesn't work anyway.
The location is correct because the image is in the same folder of the script.